# mysql order by greatest then second greatest

Tags: mysql

I've got a table of scores:

```
User / Score 1 / Score 2 / Score 3
Person 1: 10 21 7
Person 2: 21 4 20
Person 3: 1 5 22
```

I'm trying to sort them into the highest individual score and then second highest individual score.

The first part I can do.

I know how to `ORDER BY GREATEST(score1, score2, score3) DESC`

But I'm not sure how to set the secondary ordering by the second greatest so if it's a tie then it's decided by the players second highest score.

So ideally my results would be:

```
User / Score 1 / Score 2 / Score 3
Person 3: 1 5 22
Person 2: 21 4 20
Person 1: 10 21 7
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: They're ordered by greatest. i.e. Person 3 comes first because he has a highest score of 22, then person 2 comes second because he has a highest score of 21 and a 2nd highest score of 20, finally person 1 comes last because even though he ties with person 2 on his highest score, his second highest is only 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
   SELECT NAME, score1, score2, score3 FROM score
    ORDER BY GREATEST(score1, score2, score3) DESC,
        (score1+ score2+ score3) - GREATEST(score1, score2, score3) -
                                              LEAST(score1, score2, score3) DESC,
    LEAST(score1, score2, score3) DESC;
```

Comment: Nice answer...it looks just like mine.

Comment: It's different from yours @TimBiegeleisen as he doesn't uses `sum()` (whichs causes an sql error) and he has orders on each col not only on the last. But yeah the idea is the same

Comment: Its your answer i have just modified it when we do sum then it will become 1 row from multiple rows if we do not use group by that's y your query gives an error

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT User, score1, score2, score3 FROM YourTable
ORDER BY GREATEST(score1, score2, score3) DESC,
    (score1 + score2 + score3) - GREATEST(score1, score2, score3) - LEAST(score1, score2, score3) DESC,
LEAST(score1, score2, score3) DESC
```

Breakdown of the `ORDER BY` statement:

- The first row orders by the greatest value
- The second row orders by the middle value (i.e. the total minus the largest and smallest)
- The third row orders by the smallest value

Comment: I'm think I'm being thick here. I'm getting a mysql error. Adjusting your code to fit my fields I've got: SELECT * FROM players
ORDER BY GREATEST(player_serve1, player_serve2, player_serve3),
    SUM(player_serve1, player_serve2, player_serve3) - GREATEST(player_serve1, player_serve2, player_serve3) - LEAST(player_serve1, player_serve2, player_serve3),
LEAST(player_serve1, player_serve2, player_serve3) DESC

Comment: You get an sql-error on your statement with `sum`. You can try it in this fiddle (just copy your statement, as I can't link it with en select which results an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98e72

Comment: To "can't you juste use an `order by`". I think he has a szenario where every user has several tries to score and the winner is the one with the highest score over all tries. So only because a user has the highest score in turn 1 doesn't mean hes the best overall. Like jimbeeer has stated in his comment above.